# create a link to stored documents on a network drive

Tags: custom-object

I would like to have a hyperlink on my Custom Object view to connect to documents stored on a network drive.

Comment: On which network drive are your files placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Salesforce runs in "the cloud" and is not part of your network, you would need to make the resource externally available if you are not willing to put files as static resources inside Salesforce (or if you have too many resources).  This is the main reason why Salesforce only accepts URLs over HTTP(S) in configuring objects or external resources.

The complicating factor is that Salesforce doesn't really run locally for your users, so trying to connect to a network drive would be tricky without setting up some kind of remote connection, which I don't think Salesforce has by default (at least not for network drives).